# endpoint url error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, jquery

i tried to explain my problem.

I use jquery to upload in a Sharepoint list an image. The file for this image containt a single quote and space.

```
fileName="Test ' ";
var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);
return jQuery.ajax(
        url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: arrayBuffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
        },
        success: function(result) {
        }
    });
```

The error is

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value`enter code here`":"L'expression \u00ab\u00a0web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('bibli_photo_gare')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='test '.jpg')\u00a0\u00bb n'est pas valide."}}}
```

When i delete space and single quote, there is no error. Can someone help me ?

sorry for my english !!

Comment: Please try to use Curly quotes and save (Test  ’ )

Answer (score 0):

You should have to detect when a file name has simple or double quotes. If it does, your final JS code should be like this, in this case:

```
fileName="Test \' ";
```